# How to convert a dataframe to a worksheet (Python 3.8)?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl, worksheet

```
for file in all_files:
    df = pd.read_excel(file,sheet_name='Application')
    new_df=df.iloc[2:4,]
```

After the lines of code above, I want to convert the dataframe "new_df" to a worksheet to un-merge columns of the excel sheet. What I tried was this:
`ws=openpyxl.utils.dataframe.dataframe_to_rows(new_df, index=True, header=True)` 
according to https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.utils.dataframe.html
but I get an error saying "Attribute error: module 'openpyxl.utils' has no attribute 'dataframe'. How do I fix this? Or is there another approach to un-merge columns?

All the imports I used:

````
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import numpy
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import utils
import requests
import urllib3
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils.cell import range_boundaries```
````

Comment: Try `from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows`, based on the docs: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pandas.html

Comment: On a side note, you've got too many redundant imports. Like `import pandas as pd` and then `from pandas import DataFrame`. After the first `pd` import, you can do `pd.DataFrame`. For `from openpyxl import utils` - are you using `utils.<something>` anywhere in your code? If not, that's an unneeded import. And for reference, you don't need to add _all_ the imports your code has. Just the one's related to openpyxl.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: @aneroid thank you so much, your solution as fixed the problem

Comment: @Michael Okay, have posted that as an answer for future visitors who may have the same problem. Feel free to **["accept"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/193893) and [vote up](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up)**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [openpyxl-pandas docs](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pandas.html):

```py
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
```